# React.createElement: type is invalid when rendering an SVG using svgr and an array of svg images

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, syntax-error, storybook

We are using svgr with our Storybook instance to render any one of a list of svg images in a specific folder. To manage the list, we have an array and we use a prop (svgImage) passed to our  component to render the  markup with the appropriate icon.

Everything renders correctly, however we get the following error when we run tests on our code:

console.error
Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

```
Check the render method of `Icon`.
    at Icon (/components/Icon.tsx:57:3)
    at div
    at form
    at div
    at Search (/components/Search.tsx:12:12)

  117 |
  118 |   return (<i className={iconClassName} aria-hidden='true'>
> 119 |     <SvgImage />
      |     ^
  120 |   </i>
  121 |   );
  122 | };
```

Here is the code for Icon.tsx:

```
import React from 'react';

import '../shared/base/_global/_icons.scss';
import ArrowDown from '../shared/svgs/intf_arrow-down.svg';
import ArrowLeft from '../shared/svgs/intf_arrow-left.svg';
import ArrowRight from '../shared/svgs/intf_arrow-right.svg';
import ArrowUp from '../shared/svgs/intf_arrow-up.svg';
import Calendar from '../shared/svgs/intf_calendar.svg';
import ChevronLeft from '../shared/svgs/intf_chevron-left.svg';
import ChevronRight from '../shared/svgs/intf_chevron-right.svg';
import CloseCircleOutline from '../shared/svgs/intf_close_circle-outline.svg';
import CloseCircleSolid from '../shared/svgs/intf_close_circle-solid.svg';
import Cross from '../shared/svgs/intf_cross.svg';
import DeleteOutline from '../shared/svgs/intf_delete-outline.svg';
import DownloadSolid from '../shared/svgs/intf_download-solid.svg';
import ErrorCircleOutline from '../shared/svgs/intf_error_circle-outline.svg';
import GeolocationArrow from '../shared/svgs/intf_geolocation-arrow.svg';
import Geolocation from '../shared/svgs/intf_geolocation.svg';
import HelpCircleOutline from '../shared/svgs/intf_help_circle-outline.svg';
import InfoCircleOutline from '../shared/svgs/intf_info_circle-outline.svg';
import Launch from '../shared/svgs/intf_launch.svg';
import LocationPinOutline from '../shared/svgs/intf_location_pin-outline.svg';
import MailOutline from '../shared/svgs/intf_mail-outline.svg';
import Menu from '../shared/svgs/intf_menu.svg';
import Minus from '../shared/svgs/intf_minus.svg';
import PhoneOutline from '../shared/svgs/intf_phone-outline.svg';
import Placeholder from '../shared/svgs/ill_placeholder.svg';
import Plus from '../shared/svgs/intf_plus.svg';
import Resize from '../shared/svgs/intf_resize.svg';
import Search from '../shared/svgs/intf_search.svg';
import Tick from '../shared/svgs/intf_tick.svg';
import WarningOutline from '../shared/svgs/intf_warning-outline.svg';
import One from '../shared/svgs/intf_one.svg';
import Two from '../shared/svgs/intf_two.svg';
import Three from '../shared/svgs/intf_three.svg';
import Four from '../shared/svgs/intf_four.svg';
import Five from '../shared/svgs/intf_five.svg';
import Facebook from '../shared/svgs/intf_facebook.svg';
import Instagram from '../shared/svgs/intf_instagram.svg';
import Twitter from '../shared/svgs/intf_twitter.svg';
import Youtube from '../shared/svgs/intf_youtube.svg';
import Linkedin from '../shared/svgs/intf_linkedin.svg';
import Car from '../shared/svgs/intf_car.svg';
import Clock from '../shared/svgs/intf_clock.svg';
import TickOutline from '../shared/svgs/intf_tick_circle-outline.svg';
import PlaySolid from '../shared/svgs/intf_play-solid.svg';
import Play from '../shared/svgs/intf_play.svg';

export interface IconProps {
  svgImage: string;
  iconSize?: 'small' | 'medium' | 'base';
  extraClasses?: string;
  isIllustrative?: boolean;
}

export const Icon: React.FC<IconProps> = ({
  svgImage,
  iconSize,
  extraClasses,
  isIllustrative
}) => {
  const iconNames: {[key: string]: string} = {
    ArrowDown: ArrowDown,
    ArrowLeft: ArrowLeft,
    ArrowRight: ArrowRight,
    ArrowUp: ArrowUp,
    Calendar: Calendar,
    ChevronLeft: ChevronLeft,
    ChevronRight: ChevronRight,
    CloseCircleOutline: CloseCircleOutline,
    CloseCircleSolid: CloseCircleSolid,
    Cross: Cross,
    DeleteOutline: DeleteOutline,
    DownloadSolid: DownloadSolid,
    ErrorCircleOutline: ErrorCircleOutline,
    GeolocationArrow: GeolocationArrow,
    Geolocation: Geolocation,
    HelpCircleOutline: HelpCircleOutline,
    InfoCircleOutline: InfoCircleOutline,
    Launch: Launch,
    LocationPinOutline: LocationPinOutline,
    MailOutline: MailOutline,
    Menu: Menu,
    Minus: Minus,
    PhoneOutline: PhoneOutline,
    Placeholder: Placeholder,
    Plus: Plus,
    Resize: Resize,
    Search: Search,
    Tick: Tick,
    TickOutline: TickOutline,
    WarningOutline: WarningOutline,
    One: One,
    Two: Two,
    Three: Three,
    Four: Four,
    Five: Five,
    Facebook: Facebook,
    Instagram: Instagram,
    Twitter: Twitter,
    Linkedin: Linkedin,
    Youtube: Youtube,
    Car: Car,
    Clock: Clock,
    PlaySolid: PlaySolid,
    Play: Play
  };

  let SvgImage = iconNames[svgImage];

  let iconClassName = isIllustrative ? 'icon' : 'c-icon';
  if (iconSize) {
    iconClassName = `${iconClassName} c-icon--${iconSize} ${extraClasses}`;
  } else {
    iconClassName = `${iconClassName} ${extraClasses}`;
  }

  return (<i className={iconClassName} aria-hidden='true'>
    <SvgImage />
  </i>
  );
};

Icon.defaultProps = {
  svgImage: 'PhoneOutline',
  extraClasses: ''
};
```

I haven't worked much with React and my team is struggling to figure out how we can resolve the issue so we can get along with our unit test writing.

We have tried playing around with different .storybook/main.js configurations with no luck. This is the current svg rule.

```
    // Default rule for images /\.(svg|ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|ttf|woff|woff2|cur|ani|pdf)(\?.*)?$/
    const fileLoaderRule = config.module.rules.find(rule => rule.test && rule.test.test('.svg'));
    fileLoaderRule.exclude = pathToInlineSvg;

    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.svg$/,
      include: pathToInlineSvg,
      // enforce: 'pre',
      use: [
        {
          loader: require.resolve('@svgr/webpack'),
        },
      ]
    },
```

We have also tried using any of those imports directly as output in Icon.tsx, e.g. , and getting the same error.

```
  return (<i className={iconClassName} aria-hidden='true'>
    <ArrowDown />
  </i>
```

While using this code

```
  return (<i className={iconClassName} aria-hidden='true'>
    <img src={"svgImage"} />
  </i>
```

removes the error, however the output isn't what we need( image tag rather than svg).

Answer (score 0):

for use svg image we have 2 method or more , but i will explain two method:

method 1:

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import angle from './angle.svg';

const Icon = () => {
  const iconNames = {
    logo: logo,
    angle: angle
  };

  let SvgImage = iconNames["logo"];

  return (<i className={'icon'} aria-hidden='true'>
    <img src={SvgImage} alt={'alt'} />
  </i>
  );
};

export default Icon;
```

in this method we import image and pass to src props in img component ;

```
import svgSrc from "path.svg";
<img src={svgSrc}  />
```

method 2 :

```
import {ReactComponent as logo} from './logo.svg';
import {ReactComponent as angle} from './angle.svg';

const Icon = () => {
  const iconNames = {
    logo: logo,
    angle: angle
  };

  let SvgImage = iconNames["logo"];

  return (<i className={'icon'} aria-hidden='true'>
    <SvgImage />
  </i>
  );
};

export default Icon;
```

this method create component from image and we can use it :

```
import {ReactComponet as SvgSrc} from "path.svg";
<SvgSrc  />
```

this code's just for example

Change line 119 in your Icon.tsx to :

```
return (<i className={iconClassName} aria-hidden='true'>
> 119 |     <img src={SvgImage} />
  120 | </i>
```

And you need to know in below code you must pass path to img component :

```
return (<i className={iconClassName} aria-hidden='true'>
    <img src={"path.svg"} />
</i>
```